# Listen to event click through the onclick native method VueJs

Tags: javascript, laravel, vuejs2, vue-component

Listen to event click through the onclick native method

I'm using the following package [laravel-datatables](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables) from the side of the backup with laravel, which I understand is that it is not possible to render flyer components so I try to make the event listener click manually

From the backend I return an action column with two buttons

```
Route::get('/users', function(){
    $model = App\User::query();
    return DataTables::eloquent($model)
                ->addColumn('action', function(){
                    return '<a  onclick="return clickRow(this)"  class="btn btn-dark btn-sm ">
                                <span class="fa fa-edit"></span>
                            </a>
                            <a href="#"   class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
                                <span class="fa fa-remove"></span>
                            </a>';
                })
                ->rawColumns(['action'])
                ->make(true);
})->name('users');
```

As it is observed I have an onclick event in the html which I want to know if it is possible to listen from my components of VueJS

```
methods :{
    clickRow(event){
        console.log(event);
    },
....
```

The code of the buttons is returned from the backup with laravel using the package that I mentioned in the front jquery datatables, so the only way listeners can listen is how I imagined it.

it is currently telling me that the clickRow function is not defined. Is there any way to do this? If I'm mistaken in concepts it would also be great to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding a regular Vue event listener.

Instead of:

```
onclick="return clickRow(this)"
```

Do one of the two below:

- If you want to prevent the default behavior of `a`:

  ```
  @click.prevent="clickRow"
  ```
- If you just want to handle the click event:

  ```
  @click="clickRow"
  ```

Example:

```
                return '<a @click.prevent="clickRow" class="btn btn-dark btn-sm ">
                            <span class="fa fa-edit"></span>
                        </a>
                        <a href="#"   class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
                            <span class="fa fa-remove"></span>
                        </a>';
```

Comment: I tried all the options of times, but apparently the package only adds the String @ click.prevent but not the appropriate rendering to react to the events

Comment: The code of the buttons is returned from the backup with laravel using the package that I mentioned in the front jquery datatables, so the only way listeners can listen is how I imagined it.

Comment: Hm.. So I think it is not being managed. You'll have to use `onclick="return clickRow(this)"` and declare the `function clickRow(...) {` globally.

Comment: Yes, until now it was my only possibility, but it is not clear to me how it would do since when I click on the button I get all the data to set some values ​​within the vue component instance

Comment: You can access the instance declaring it like `window.app = new Vue({...` and later using `app` to access its values.

Comment: The detail is that it is not a single instance, it is a single file component

Comment: Works the same. You would add the `window.app = new Vue({...` in the main.js and use `window.app` to access it everywhere else